# How to make a subfigure span the two columns in IEEEtrans style?

Tags: floats, ieeetran

I have three figures that I want to put side by side for the sake of comparison, I am using IEEEtrans. I found solutions for how an equation spans the two columns but not for contiguous figures, any ideas comments will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: My problem is similar to this but when i apply the given solution all my figure comes in one page which is very awkward any comment will be appriciated

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "[Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the starred `figure*` environment without any `[htpb]` specifiers. Try to keep your figure declaration closer to the text you want to put next to.

Also check the wonderful description from Frank Mittelbach about figure positioning.

[How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

```
\documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}%
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} %<- For dummy text
\usepackage{mwe} %<- For dummy images

% Remove the trailing whitespace from citations
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}

% Training subcaption package to comply with
% IEEE standards. We can ignore the warning
% generated by caption.sty which is due to 
% the redefinition of \@makecaption
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{periodspace}{.\quad}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize,labelsep=periodspace,singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[sub]{font=footnotesize,singlelinecheck=true}

\title{The research}
\author{The researcher}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\kant[1]
\end{abstract}

\kant[1-5]

\begin{figure*}%
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.4\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
\caption{cap a}%
\label{subfiga}%
\end{subfigure}\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}{.4\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}%
\caption{cap b}%
\label{subfigb}%
\end{subfigure}\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}{.4\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-c}%
\caption{cap c}%
\label{subfigc}%
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{The proper caption}
\label{figabc}
\end{figure*}

\kant[6-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]