# Error with figure spanning double column in IEEEtran

Tags: floats, ieeetran, columns

I am trying to integrate a figure spanning both columns as shown in [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139214/how-to-make-a-subfigure-span-the-two-columns-in-ieeetrans-style) or [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34063/figure-span-to-one-column-on-double-column-page), but it does not seem to work for me. And I can't figure out why.

The code:

```
\subsection{Anfälligkeiten}
%
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PointsOfFailure.png}
    \caption{Points of failure on a password's way}
    \label{fig_sim}
\end{figure*}
%
\begin{itemize}
    \item   Social Engineering
    \item   Single Point of Failure: Nutzer
    %
    \item   Phishing
    \item   Shoulder Surfing
    \item   Key Logger/ Video Aufnahmen
    %
    \item   Replay Angriff
    %
    \item   Dictionary
    \item   Brute-Force
\end{itemize}
```

Which gives me the following errors
[image]

I thought it was about the next page not being filled (because the help text said that floats are not typically placed on the first side). But I filled it (\lipsum[1-14]) and the error still occurs :P

Sorry for stupid german-english. Textstudio runs in a kind of mixture. Fehler = Error and Zeile = line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I needed the package graphicx and not graphics ...

Comment: Welcome to http://tex.stackexchange.com/ Isabella. What is your prologue `\documentclass, ....\usepackage`?

Comment: It is solved I used \usepackage{graphics} at first, but apparently I need to use \usepackage{graphicx}. It works now. But I have to wait for 2 days to mark it as solved :P

But thanks anyways! :D

Comment: I am happy that you have resolve the question. Best regards Isabella.